# if, else if, else function isn't accurately displaying results

Tags: c++, function, c++11, if-statement

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
                       // prototype functions
void DisplayResult(float MaxOrMin);

float FindMinimum(float Array[5]);

float FindMaximum(float Array[5]);
                //Global Variables
float Array[5];

float MaxOrMin = 3;

float FindMin;
float FindMax;
           //Main Function
int main()
{
            cout << "Please enter 5 numbers: " << endl;

    for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        cin >> Array[i];    // input for array
    }
        cout << "Please enter '0' for minimum or '9' for maximum:"  << endl;

        cin >> MaxOrMin;    // input 0 or 9 for min or max

                    //Calling Functions
FindMinimum(Array);
FindMaximum(Array);

DisplayResult(MaxOrMin);
                return 0;
}
                             //Function to find Minimum
float FindMinimum(float Array[5])
{

float FindMin = Array[0];

    for (int y=1;y<5;y++)
    {
        if(Array[y] < FindMin)
            FindMin = Array[y];
    }

return FindMin;
}
                              //Function to find Maximum
float FindMaximum(float Array[5])
{
float FindMax = Array[0];

    for (int x=1;x<5;x++)
    {
        if(Array[x] > FindMax)
            FindMax = Array[x];
    }
return FindMax;
}
```

This last part is my if, else if, else funtion:

```
//Function to display minimum or maximum result
void DisplayResult(float MaxOrMin)
{
if (MaxOrMin == 0)
    cout << "Minimum is: " << FindMin << endl;

    else if (MaxOrMin == 9)
        cout << "Maximum is: " << FindMax << endl;

        else
            cout << "Invalid Input" << endl;
}
```

My project is to create a program using functions to take user input on a 5 float array. Then find the max and min and display whichever the user asks for.

Here is where my problem comes in. For both max(input 9) and min(input 0) I am getting "0". However any other input correctly returns my "Invalid Input" message.

I'm not getting any errors or warnings or errors at all on eclipse. My professor has told me that my problem was likely with my void function for displaying results. I am hoping someone could point me in the right direction here.

Apologies for my formatting and/or if this question is too basic for this site.

Comment: don't apologize for formatting. Just format your code properly.

Comment: I am extremely new to coding in general (not just C++) so I am open to any suggested resources anyone might have to improve my formatting.

Comment: @Rob: Patience and a keyboard.

Comment: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html , https://zed0.co.uk/clang-format-configurator/ , http://format.krzaq.cc/ , http://clang-format.me/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your `FindMinimum()` (and the same with `FindMaximum()`) function compute the minimum (maximum) in a local variable and return it but you, in `main()` don't receive they in correct variables

So the computed value is lost.

I mean... instead of

```
FindMinimum(Array);
FindMaximum(Array);
```

you should write

```
FindMin = FindMinimum(Array);
FindMax = FindMaximum(Array);
```

Comment: I made the change you suggested and it works perfectly. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You misunderstand how local and global variables work. Your Find* functions shadow the globals with locals and thus they don't appear to do anything.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. I will try to gain a better understanding of how both work.